# can't publish in window var with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I can't make webpack plugin work properly neither the incode way to declare global variable in a webpack interpreted code here is my code.

```js
//webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
 mode: 'development',
 devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  entry: [
   './assets/js/main.js',
   './assets/sass/style.scss',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
   rules: [
    {
     test: /\.css$/,
     use: [
      'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
     ],
    },
    {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
     {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
       name: '[name].css',
      }
     },
     {
      loader: 'extract-loader'
     },
     {
      loader: 'css-loader?-url'
     },
     {
      loader: 'sass-loader'
     }
    ],
      },
    {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.csv$/,
        loader: 'csv-loader',
        options: {
          dynamicTyping: true,
          header: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.xml$/,
        use: [
          'xml-loader',
        ],
      },
      {test: /datatables\.net.*/, loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false'},
   ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery',
     'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      '_': 'lodash',
      'moment': 'moment',
      'window.moment': 'moment'
    })
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
};





//main.js

// this code should not be required but webpack plugin don't work and even this code don't work
console.log( jQuery );
window.jQuery = jQuery;
console.log( window.jQuery );







//package.json
{
  "name": "pulsaredbupdate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "csv-parser": "^2.3.2",
    "datatables.net-autofill-dt": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.6.1",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-dt": "^1.5.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-editor-dt": "^1.6.3",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-dt": "^3.3.0",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-dt": "^3.1.6",
    "datatables.net-keytable-dt": "^2.5.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-dt": "^1.1.1",
    "datatables.net-rowreorder-dt": "^1.2.6",
    "datatables.net-scroller-dt": "^2.0.1",
    "datatables.net-searchpanes-dt": "^1.0.1",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.3.1",
    "extract-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jszip": "^3.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.65",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}







//console returns :
main.js:2 ƒ ( selector, context ) {

  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
  return new jQuery…
main.js:4 ƒ ( selector, context ) {

  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
  return new jQuery…
content.js:5 --------init----------- http://pulsaredbupdate.test/
window.jQuery
undefined
```

In this snippet I describe how I declared webpack.config.js and my main.js file.
I did search in webpack documentation and in Google but I can't figure out why it doesn't work properly
jQuery variable exists and work well in main.js but when I call it in browser console it doesn't exist and console returns "undefined".
Thank you for your help

Comment: where do you import `jquery`? Shouldn't it be part of your entry? There could be a shared js file that has all your external stuff and one for your app. How does your package.json look like?

Comment: In webpack.config.js file in the plugin webpack.ProvidePlugin method I call jQuery and other libraries like lodash that should be loaded in local jquery var and window global var. And it's working for the jquery local var that is available in my main.js file but not in browser scope.

Comment: I edited my question to include package.json so you can check it

Comment: Can someone please help me ? I'm still stuck with this.